# Does gravity have two directions?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, earth, geometry

Imagine a particle that interacts strongly with gravity, but not with any of the other forces, and does not interact with normal matter (this may be analogous to the description of dark matter, I'm not sure). If this particle was travelling towards earth, where would its rest state be?

[image]

Based on the above diagram I would assume the rest point would be at the peak of the graph, in the area between the outer core and upper mantle, at a radius of roughly 3,500km.

This would mean that gravity has two directions. If the aforementioned particle was at a radius of 2,000km, it would be attracted 'up' towards 3,500km. And if it was at 8,000km, it would be attracted 'down' towards 3,500km.

Could this be considered a kind of polarity in the gravitational field?

Comment: Notice that what you are looking at on the left hand side of the plot is acceleration.  The assumed direction of this acceleration is towards the center of the planet (which is the direction of "attraction").  The "rest point" of any object should be where the acceleration is zero, which is at the center.  The particle that you describe would not come to rest at the point of maximum acceleration at ~3500 km, it would be further accelerated towards the center of the planet.

Comment: Yes:  Up,  and Down.  :-)

Comment: I didn't understood the question at all. But it seems you are talking of the derivative of the acceleration. The peak is not a rest point.

Comment: Skip down to the middle of page 5 in this link: http://accounts.smccd.edu/gristg/p211/p211gravity.pdf.  The analysis that begins there should be helpful in understanding the gravitational force that acts on a particle inside the Earth.

Comment: @igael, the confusion comes from me interpreting this graph wrong. I thought that, because there was an effective force of zero g in the centre of the planet, and it gets close to zero g somewhere out in space, that the maximum attractive point was represented by the peak of this graph. I now understand it doesn't work like that at all. Really, its quite obvious. but things are only obvious when you know them!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a spherical shell with homogeneous mass, any object outside of it will feel a radial attraction, while any object inside will feel no gravitational force at all, since all the vectors cancel out. So, try to picture Earth as a collection of shells with distinct radii and density. If the particle is positioned inside some shells, but outside others, it will only perceive attraction from the inner layers. Therefore, once the particle we're dealing with crosses the higher density region, it will completely ignore its existence and just get attracted by whatever's still inside.

Comment: Thankyou, that nested shells concept is an interesting way to think about it. So the rest point of this particle would be at the zero point of the graph?

Comment: are you sure when you write *while any object inside will feel no gravitational force at all* ? see again the shell theorem for not empty spheres

Comment: @igael:  I'm pretty sure that the first sentence refers only to hollow spherical shells;  the transition to "not-empty" spheres is in the second sentence.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : sure. It was just an advice to reword the first sentence to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

> If this particle was travelling towards earth, where would its rest state be?

If the particle is moving fast enough, the answer is nowhere.

The particle will gain speed as it approaches the center of the Earth. The speed will be rather high at the point of closest approach to the center. The particle will lose speed as it moves away from the center of the Earth. The particle will exit the Earth with exactly the same speed it had when it first entered the Earth.

Note that "fast enough" means about 11 km/second, which is quite slow compared to the speed of light. Neutrinos come very close to your hypothetical particle. (Neutrinos are subject to the weak interaction, but this is very weak.) Almost all neutrinos that enter the Earth exit it shortly thereafter, never to interact with the Earth again.